# resolv.conf сбрасывается после каждой перезагрузки сервера

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

После каждой перезагрузки сервера приходится вручную менять файл resolv.conf (туда записывается ip моего сервера, а не то что нужно) командой

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

Можно ли как-то избежать этого? Не понимаю, почему он сбрасывается. А когда там записано не 8.8.8.8, то curl, websocket перестаёт работать.

Сервер под ubuntu 14.04

Содержимое **/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 141.8.196.103
  gateway 141.8.196.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 141.8.196.0
  broadcast 141.8.196.255
  dns-nameservers 141.8.192.2

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
dns-search google.com
dns-nameservers dnsserverip
```

Содержимое **/etc/resolv.conf**:

```
nameserver 141.8.192.2
```

Comment: Если у вас автополучение IP попробуйте в /etc/dhcpcd.conf добавить `nohook resolv.conf` или дописать resolv.conf к существующей строке nohook (через запятую)

Comment: Попробовал только что. 
После sudo reboot опять resolv.conf сбросился на nameserver *ip сервера*. Что вообще должно быть в правильном resolv.conf? раньше никогда не было проблем с этим. Да и ничего необычного не ставил. Просто однажды с утра обнаружил, что перестал curl работать. Докопал до этого файла, когда меняю на 8.8.8.8 - всё норм....

Comment: у вас, вероятно, стоит resolvconf, который собирает /etc/resolv.conf автоматом при каждом запуске. если это так, то /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d содержит части шаблона, которые вы можете отредактировать

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, содержимое `/etc/network/interfaces` и `/etc/resolv.conf` (до ваших изменений).

Comment: Добавил. Так они выглядят после каждой перезагрузки....

Comment: resolv.conf в ubuntu с некоторого времени переписывается динамически

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас в файле `/etc/network/interfaces` записаны конфликтующие настройки.

уточните у администратора вашей сети, как на вашем компьютере должна быть сконфигурирована сеть: динамически или статически. если динамически, тогда закомментируйте первую секцию, начинающуюся с:

```
iface eth0 inet static
```

если статически — вторую, начинающуюся с:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

а заодно уточните и ip-адрес dns-сервера(-ов). ведь тот, что сейчас используется, видимо, уже нерабочий и подлежит замене. как несложно догадаться, он(-и) может(-гут) быть указан(-ы) директивой `dns-nameservers` (если будет несколько, то через пробел).

если администратор ничего нового по поводу dns-сервера(-ов) не расскажет, то укажите там, например, google-вские публичные серверы:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

---

доп. информация: https://wiki.debian.org/ru/NetworkConfiguration